# Testing Angular Directive and triggering valuechanges

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I am trying to test my directive, but not 100% sure how to do it. The directive is controlling the decimal separator, and the decimal places allowed after the separator. It listens on valueChanges and if more decimals are provided it changes the newValue back to the oldValue. (ommited directive logic for simplicity):

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[restrictedDecimals]'
})
export class InstrumentDecimalsDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input() decimals = null;
    @Input() separator = ',';
    valueSubscription: Subscription;

    constructor(@Self() @Optional() public ngControl: NgControl) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.ngControl.valueChanges.pipe(distinctUntilChanged(), pairwise()).subscribe(([oldValue, newValue]) => {
            this.runCheck(oldValue, newValue);
        });
    }
...
}
```

created a test component called `InstrumentDecimalTestComponent` to have an HTML template to work with in the test:

```
<input type="text" restrictedDecimals decimals="2" />
```

and the test case:

```
describe('InstrumentDecimalsDirective', () => {
   let fixture: ComponentFixture<any>;
   beforeEach(async () => {
       const NG_CONTROL_PROVIDER = {
           provide: NgControl,
           useClass: class extends NgControl {
               control = new FormControl();
               viewToModelUpdate() {}
           }
       };

       const testModuleMetadata: TestModuleMetadata = {
           imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule],
           declarations: [InstrumentDecimalTestComponent, InstrumentDecimalsDirective]
       };
       fixture = TestBed.configureTestingModule(testModuleMetadata).overrideDirective(InstrumentDecimalsDirective, {
           add: { providers: [NG_CONTROL_PROVIDER] },
         }).createComponent(InstrumentDecimalTestComponent);
       fixture.detectChanges();
   });



   it('should reject input with more decimals than allowed', fakeAsync(() => {
       const input = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.directive(InstrumentDecimalsDirective))[0].nativeElement;
       const inputEvent = new Event('input');
       input.value = '1,12';
       input.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);
       input.value = '1,123';
       input.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);

       tick(500);
       fixture.detectChanges();
       expect(input.value).toBe('1,12');
   }));

});
```

Please point out what is the missing part!

Answer (score 0):

I would add a `console.log` inside of here and if you don't see the log, that means `input.value =`  does not trigger `valueChanges`.

```
this.ngControl.valueChanges.pipe(distinctUntilChanged(), pairwise()).subscribe(([oldValue, newValue]) => {
            console.log('value changes triggered !!');
            this.runCheck(oldValue, newValue);
        });
```

Instead of changing the value using `input.value =` , try adding a `form` or `ngModel` (2 way binding) to the `InstrumentDecimalTestComponent` and change the value of this `form` or `ngModel` and see if the `valueChanges` in the directive is triggered.

Also, maybe `NG_CONTROL_PROVIDERS` is overriding critical functionality.